# Is it ok to connect to mongoDB via mongoose if connection is already there

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it necessary to check if a connection to a MongoDB has already been established or is it OK to always `mongoose.connect(...)` regardless of the connection status?

Comment: Context is everything and without any code it is impossible to give you a helpful answer. The standard practice is to use `mongoose.connect()` once or use `mongoose.createConnection()` if you intent to have multiple connections. Regardless of which you choose "*Each connection, whether created with mongoose.connect or mongoose.createConnection are all backed by an internal configurable connection pool defaulting to a maximum size of 100*"

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you are using a framework such as Next, Nest, Meteor etc then they will have their own recommended approach so always consult the docs.